# Why does my first if statement always return true even if it doesn't match the if criteria?

Tags: python

I tried printing the Score to ensure it was receiving the value I entered and it was which was even more baffling.  Ex. I tried entering in 0.85 and it printed A.  Why is that?

```
try:
    Score = raw_input("What is the Score? ")
    if Score >= 0.90 < 1.01:
        print Score
        print "A"
    elif Score >= 0.80 < 0.90:
        print "B"
    elif Score >= 0.7 < 0.8:
        print "C"
    elif Score >= 0.6 < 0.7:
        print "D"
    elif Score >= 0.6 >= 0.0:
        print "F"
except:
    print "ERROR: You did not enter a number or did not enter the number in the format '0.00'"
```

Comment: `if Score >= 0.90 and Score < 1.01: ...`  (and repeat that technique for all the other elif conditionals as well).

Comment: or even `0.90 <= Score < 1.01`

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

(I had this wrong in my first answer.)

In addition to @Alex's point that you need `float(raw_input(...))` to get a numeric type... this `if` statement:

```
if Score >= 0.90 < 1.01:
```

is equivalent to:

```
if Score >= 0.90 and 0.90 < 1.01
```

You probably want this instead:

```
if 0.90 <= Score < 1.01:
```

or this:

```
if Score >= 0.90 and Score < 1.01:
```

Comment: @Rawing I believe you're right! Sorry, the exact same Python trick that I suggested at the end is what makes that true. :-) Will edit.

Comment: @user2357112 Yup, as pointed out by Rawing a little while ago. I just made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem 1: `raw_input`

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input): `raw_input` "reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that".

You need to cast it to a `float` to compare it with numeric types.

```
Score = float(raw_input("What is the Score? "))
```

#### Problem 2: chained comparisons (as seen in @smarx answer)

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#not-in) "`x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false)."

So `if 0.90 <= Score < 1.01:` instead of `if Score >= 0.90 < 1.01:`

Comment: Not sure what you mean... `'0.4' < 0.5` evaluates to `False` for me. Secondly think we might be saying the same thing. I was attempting to explain that the chained comparison syntax differs from the code OP posted (assuming OP wanted to use chained comparisons).

Comment: What I meant is that, had chaining worked as the OP thought it would, the final `elif` would still be wrong: `elif Score >= 0.6 >= 0.0:` would have evaluated to `Score >= 0.6 and Score >= 0.0`.

Comment: I'm not sure why it seemed to have worked on my system without the cast; that may have been related to my previous comment.

Comment: @SQB ah gotcha re. the last `elif`.